# mysql_real_escape_string doesn't work with post PHP

Tags: php, mysql, post

Maybe I'm wrong but for me its not working,

I'm trying to do the `mysql_real_escape_string()` function with `$_POST['value'];` like this,

```
mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['value']);
```

but its not working, but if I try this,

```
$value = $_POST['value'];
mysql_real_escape_string($value);
```

it works perfectly, any suggestion why?

EDIT:

My code is like this,

```
$post = array('id', 'name');
$postArray = array();
foreach($post as $pa){
    $postArray[$pa] = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[$pa]);
}
```

Comment: That…shouldn't be true. Maybe it would help to offer a little more context and some examples?

Comment: After the edit, that code sample looks 100% correct to me. What are some inputs and the incorrect output they produce?

Comment: And oh wait yup. @Amber is so totes right. Looks…um…80% right, then ^_^;

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you assigning the result of `mysql_real_escape_string()` to anything? It doesn't modify the variable in-place.

```
$value = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['value']);
```

---

**To respond to your edit - shouldn't your `foreach` be looping over `$post`, not `$postArray`?**

```
foreach($postArray as $pa){
```

should be...

```
foreach($post as $pa){
```

---

**Second edit: please use this code and tell us what it outputs:**

```
var_dump($_POST);
$post = array('id', 'name');
$postArray = array();
foreach($post as $pa){
    $postArray[$pa] = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[$pa]);
}
var_dump($postArray);
```

---

**Final edit:**

Okay, your problem is that your incoming post variables are being read as arrays, and thus you can't call `mysql_real_escape_string()` directly on those (because it's designed for strings, not arrays).

Change your code to this:

```
$post = array('id', 'name');
$postArray = array();
foreach($post as $pa){
    if(is_array($_POST[$pa])) {
        $postArray[$pa] = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[$pa][0]);
    } else {
        $postArray[$pa] = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[$pa]);
    }
}
```

and things should work.

Comment: After your second edit, I don't see any other issues with your code - can you try putting a `var_dump($postArray);` after your code to see what's in it, and/or show us more context code?

Comment: Please post a `var_dump()` of both `$_POST` before the loop and `$postArray` after the loop, from the same run of the script.

Comment: I dont know whats wrong, but when I changed it just to $_POST its ok, once I changed again to the mysql_real, is everything blank.

Comment: I'm getting this one, array(6) { ["company"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(2) "AL" } ["type"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(2) "CD" } ["code"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(8) "CICPROMO" } ["title"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(12) "Travel agent" } ["amount"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(5) "false" } ["saveDiscount"]=> string(4) "Save" } array(5) { ["company"]=> NULL ["type"]=> NULL ["code"]=> NULL ["title"]=> NULL ["amount"]=> NULL }